# how to remove or disable woocommerce order review in checkout page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

In the checkout page, there is a review order table on the bottom. I want to remove the order review in checkout page. What is the remove action ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add following code into your funtions.php

```
add_filter( ‘woocommerce_product_tabs’, ‘sb_woo_remove_reviews_tab’, 98);

function sb_woo_remove_reviews_tab($tabs) { 
unset($tabs[‘reviews’]);
return $tabs;
}
```

Comment: I want to remove the order review table in checkout page. not review tab.

Comment: In your plugin folder Go To woocommerce->includes->wc-template-functions.php
Now press ctrl+f and write woocommerce_order_review and press enter. You will find a function of the same name. Just remove its body(portion that comes under{}) And its done.

Comment: Thank you. it works but is there a way like remove action to get the same result?

Comment: Sorry, i am not getting your point(remove action to get the same result).

Comment: I don't want to remove the code. I want the code to stay but i think there is a way to disable it. For example add_filter() or remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );

Comment: If I update my woocommerce plugin, it will overwrite my file.

Comment: Yes, I understand your concern. But my known method is not working as per your expectations. But you can always use google.

Answer (score 10):

You can remove the order summary table like this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
```

You could also copy the `checkout/review-order.php` template to your child theme, and modify it as desired.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.